# Como leer una linea con un formato específico de un archivo .TXT en C?

Tags: c

Tengo una archivo que contiene lineas con el siguiente formato:

```
1 +Description of Line 1+ 1 -1 4 3
2 +Description of Line 2+ -1 2 1 4
3 +Description of Line 3+ 4 -1 -1 2
```

Necesito, para cada linea, leer 6 variables. Esas variables son: id (int), description (char), param1 (int), param2(int), param3(int), param4(int).
Por tanto, los parametros cargados de la primera linea serían:

```
id = 1
description = "Description of Line 1"
param1 = 1
param2 = -1
param3 = 4
param4 = 3
```

Estoy tratando de hacerlo usando la funcion fscanf y el siguiente formato:

```
fp = fopen(filename, "r");

fscanf(fp, "%d +%[^\n]s+ %d %d %d %d\n", &id, &description, &param1, &param2, &param3, &param4);
```

Pero no lo he logrado. Necesito cargar los 6 parametros de cada linea, el problema esta al intentar leer un string entre dos simbolos de suma.

Podría alguien guiarme en cómo resolver el problema?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

La cadena de formato que necesitas es la siguiente:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d +%[^+]+ %d %d %d %d\n", &id, &description, &param1, &param2, &param3, &param4);
```

La parte de las `%d` está clara, pero la de la cadena es la que tiene truco. Normalmente para leer una cadena usaríamos `%s`, pero eso se detiene en cuanto aparezca un espacio, y no es lo que queremos en este caso. Por tanto en vez de `%s` usaremos `%[]`, que también es para leer cadenas (observa que ya no se pone la `s`), pero nos permite especificar qué juego de caracteres compone la cadena, que será el que especifiquemos entre corchetes.

En este caso he puesto `%[^+]` que significa "cualquier caracter excepto el signo más". De modo que la cadena se dará por terminada cuando aparezca el primer `+`, que es justo donde se termina la descripción.

A su vez, encerramos ese especificador `%[^+]` entre dos signos más, así: `+%[^+]+` en este caso para que los `+` que rodean a la descripción se "consuman" por `fscanf()` y no queden sin leer (ya que si no los "consumimos" de esta forma podrían dar problemas a la hora de leer el resto de parámetros que siguen en la línea).

([demo en repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/JuvenileValidInverse))